# get offline update from wsus server

Tags: windows-update, wsus, automatic-updates, wsus-offline

I have a wsus server(windows server 2019), some of the clients are correctly in the console and getting updates.(No need for internet or VPN) But some clients face the following error for updating:
***"we couldn't check for updates, because you aren't connected to the internet. make sure you have a cellular data or wi-fi connection and try again."***
And if they connect to the Internet or VPN, they will be displayed on the console and receive updates!
Where is the problem and how can I make all clients get updates from my wsus server without connecting to the server or VPN?
All clients are Windows 10.
Thanks